# How to fix SSL error in Perl LWP?

Tags: perl, ssl, lwp

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4',
    ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 }
);

my $response = $ua->get('https://www.themoviedb.org');
```

gives an error message:

> Can't connect to www.themoviedb.org:443
>
> SSL connect attempt failed error:14077410:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure at
>   /Library/Perl/5.18/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 46.

I use macOS Sierra

```
LWP->VERSION                            6.26
IO::Socket::SSL->VERSION                2.049
Net::SSLeay->VERSION                    1.72
Net::SSLeay::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER()   0x009081df
LWP::UserAgent->VERSION                 6.26
LWP::Protocol::https->VERSION           6.04
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

> Net::SSLeay::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER()   0x009081df

This is OpenSSL 0.9.8, at least 7 years old, not supporting TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 and not supporting any ECDHE ciphers. Also, no support for [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) within IO::Socket::SSL for this old version of OpenSSL.

Looking at the [SSLLabs report for www.themoviedb.org](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.themoviedb.org&s=2600%3a9000%3a202e%3aa400%3ae%3a5373%3a440%3a93a1&latest) you'll see:

> This site works only in browsers with SNI support.

Thus, you'll need to upgrade your version of OpenSSL. Note that you also need to recompile Net::SSLeay afterwards and link it to the newer OpenSSL version.